# Print the Error Report

Tags: error-handling, apport

When I start my Ubuntu 12.04, I often get an Error "Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error. If you notice further problems, try restarting the computer."

How to print or save this report in detail?

Thanks for the reply.